# Execution time overflow, when executing wihout limit

Tags: sql, performance, limit

when i use this query, everything works nice. 5 Result in 0.3587 seconds.

```
SELECT `prod_combined`.`sku`, `prod_combined`.`titel`, `prod_combined`.`preis_vk`, 
`prod_combined`.`link` 
FROM `prod_combined` 
WHERE 
(
   prod_combined.sku IN 
       (
       SELECT 
       prod_combined.sku FROM 
       (
           SELECT prod_combined.sku FROM prod_billiger 
           INNER JOIN
           prod_combined ON prod_combined.sku = prod_billiger.sku 
           WHERE rangGesamt = 1 
           AND prod_combined.aktiv = 1 
       ) q 
       JOIN prod_combined ON prod_combined.sku = q.sku)
) 
AND (aktiv = 1)
LIMIT 0,5
```

but when i use this query, it runs for approximately 3 minutes.

```
SELECT `prod_combined`.`sku`, `prod_combined`.`titel`, `prod_combined`.`preis_vk`, 
`prod_combined`.`link` 
FROM `prod_combined` 
WHERE 
(
   prod_combined.sku IN 
       (
       SELECT 
       prod_combined.sku FROM 
       (
           SELECT prod_combined.sku FROM prod_billiger 
           INNER JOIN
           prod_combined ON prod_combined.sku = prod_billiger.sku 
           WHERE rangGesamt = 1 
           AND prod_combined.aktiv = 1 
       ) q 
       JOIN prod_combined ON prod_combined.sku = q.sku)
) 
AND (aktiv = 1)
```

What im trying to do:
Get all products that are on first place (prod_billiger.rangGesamt). I get this information in "prod_billiger" table. The other productinformation comes from prod_combined.

Is there a way, to speed it up? Do i need to overthink the whole query?

Regards,
chucky2305

Comment: The query would become much more readable if you used correlation names ("tags") instead of the full table names, especially since you refer to the same table four (four!!!) times. BTW: is prod_combined.sku the primary key?

Comment: I`m sorry for that. Maybe i should start it a new way.
Regarding to my application i need to write it in a subquery. But im not familiar with these yet. Do you think you can help me?

Comment: Can't you edit the post? BTW: where does rangGesamt come from? prod_billiger?

Comment: As you can see NOW, rangGesamt comes from prod_billiger

Comment: Ok, I'll try to rewite it in the answers, then. With the only intension of getting it into a readable shape.

Comment: I used all these references, to avoid SQL syntax problems, such as "subquery returns more than one row..." etc. 
How can i start to set up a good subquery?

Comment: Well, thanks for the karma-points, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
SELECT pc.sku, pc.titel, pc.preis_vk, pc.link
FROM prod_combined AS pc 
WHERE pc.sku IN (
    SELECT sku
    FROM prod_billiger
    WHERE rangGesamt = 1
)
AND pc.aktiv=1
```

I added a synonym for prod_combined (`prod_combined AS pc`) just to make the `select` statement more concise.

This will run pretty quickly if your tables are small, or if you have an index on rangGesamt and/or aktiv.

Comment: Thanks. That was quick. And easy. ;)
In my last queries i got the error message "IN / ANY ... is not allowed"
I can`t understand why it is now accepted by MySQL

Comment: @MaxSchindler Not sure. Maybe you were doing something like `WHERE pc.sku = (SELECT sku...` instead of `WHERE pc.sku IN (SELECT sku...`.  That would throw an error if the subquery returned more than one row, which seems to be the case.  If you want to post that query I could take a quick peek at it.

Comment: I would like to, but i have dumped my testqueries. But i`m quite sure that i`ve tried it with IN and also got errors on these ones.

Thats the error i got when i tried it: (Sorry its written in german)

Diese MySQL-Version unterstützt 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' nicht

Comment: @MaxSchindler Doing some quick googling, I found some people getting that message with queries like `SELECT blah FROM table WHERE col IN (SELECT c FROM table2 LIMIT 0,2)`.  Notice that the `LIMIT` is in the subquery and not the main query.  Maybe that's what you were seeing.  I found one person who said you could work around it by doing `(SELECT c FROM (SELECT c FROM table2 LIMIT 0,2) temp)` but I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: Maybe this was my problem. Ill keep an eye on it, when i create the next queries using an "IN"

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting your query gets me to:

```
SELECT pc.sku, pc.titel, pc.preis_vk, pc.link pc
FROM prod_combined pc   
WHERE 
(
   pc.sku IN
       (
       SELECT 
       pc2.sku FROM
       (
           SELECT pc2.sku FROM 
           prod_billiger  pb
           INNER JOIN prod_combined pc2 ON pc2.sku = pb.sku
           WHERE pb.rangGesamt = 1
           AND pc2.aktiv = 1 
       ) q 
       JOIN prod_combined pc3 ON pc3.sku = q.sku
        )
) 
AND pc.aktiv = 1
;
```

, which is probably equivalient to:

```
SELECT pc.sku, pc.titel, pc.preis_vk, pc.link pc
FROM prod_combined  pc
WHERE pc.sku IN (
       SELECT q.sku 
       FROM (
           SELECT pc2.sku FROM 
           prod_billiger  pb
           INNER JOIN prod_combined pc2 ON pc2.sku = pb.sku
           WHERE pb.rangGesamt = 1
           AND pc2.aktiv = 1
           ) q
        )
AND pc.aktiv = 1
        ;
```

Which can be further reduced to:

```
SELECT pc.sku, pc.titel, pc.preis_vk, pc.link pc
FROM prod_combined  pc
WHERE EXISTS (
       SELECT *
          FROM prod_billiger  pb
          INNER JOIN prod_combined pc2 ON pc2.sku = pb.sku 
          WHERE pb.rangGesamt = 1 AND pc2.aktiv = 1
          AND pc.sku = pb.sku;
        )
AND pc.aktiv = 1
        ;
```

If "sku" is the primary key for prod_combined, the subquery can even be further reduced, to only contain "prod_billiger".

```
SELECT pc.sku, pc.titel, pc.preis_vk, pc.link pc
FROM prod_combined  pc
WHERE EXISTS (
       SELECT *
          FROM prod_billiger  pb
          WHERE pc.sku = pb.sku;
          AND pb.rangGesamt = 1 AND pc2.aktiv = 1
        )
AND pc.aktiv = 1
        ;
```

Which is more or less equivalent with:

```
SELECT pc.sku, pc.titel, pc.preis_vk, pc.link pc
FROM prod_combined  pc
WHERE pc.sku IN (
       SELECT sku
       FROM prod_billiger  pb
       WHERE pb.rangGesamt = 1 
       )
AND pc.aktiv = 1
        ;
```

If sku is also a primary (or candidate) key for prod_billiger, things can be even further reduced to:

```
SELECT pc.sku, pc.titel, pc.preis_vk, pc.link pc
FROM prod_combined  pc
JOIN prod_billiger  pb ON pc.sku = pb.sku
WHERE pb.rangGesamt = 1
AND pc.aktiv = 1
        ;
```

Comment: Yes, sku is the primary key. How can it be reduced then?